# Is there a way to get Intel's integrated gpu usage using python on Windows?

Tags: python, gpu, intel

I need to get gpu usage from intel's integrated gpu using python on Windows is there a way to pull this off?, i don't mind having to use modules.

Comment: On Linux you could parse the output of `intel_gpu_top -l`, or use whatever API it uses.  (https://gitlab.freedesktop.org/drm/igt-gpu-tools)

Comment: I think this post may help you https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67707828/how-to-get-every-seconds-gpu-usage-in-python

Comment: You can use the `subprocess.Popen` or `subprocess.run` module to run powershell commands which can give you more specific information about your GPU no matter what the vendor. Here is a link on a powershell script you can use to get your GPU, then use the subprocess module in python to run that script. If you want help with that, I can make it n answer.  https://superuser.com/a/1632853/1602552

Comment: thank you guys for the info, I forgot to specify I need it for Windows and @codester_09 the link you posted I think it just works for nvidia gpu thanks a lot anyway

Comment: @PythonKiddieScripterX It seems to be what i'm looking for :D, i'm gonna try to do it all by myself based on the link you provided in order to learn something new, in case I don't manage to get it working i'm gonna have to trouble you in the near future, thanks a lot in advance

Comment: Yeah no problem, just @ me and we can figure out something basic.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As suggested in the third comment, you can extract information from **Windows Power Shell** with the *subprocess* python package.

```py
import subprocess as sp

# raw strings avoid unicode encoding errors
gpu_mem_cmd = r'(((Get-Counter "\GPU Process Memory(*)\Local Usage").CounterSamples | where CookedValue).CookedValue | measure -sum).sum'
gpu_usage_cmd = r'(((Get-Counter "\GPU Engine(*engtype_3D)\Utilization Percentage").CounterSamples | where CookedValue).CookedValue | measure -sum).sum'

def run_command(command):
    val = sp.run(['powershell', '-Command', command], capture_output=True).stdout.decode("ascii")

    return float(val.strip().replace(',', '.'))

print()
print(" GPU Info ".center(80, '='))
print(f"GPU Memory Usage: {round(run_command(gpu_mem_cmd)/1e6,1):<6} MB")
print(f"GPU Load :        {round(run_command(gpu_usage_cmd),2):<6} %")
```

The output should be:

```
=================================== GPU Info ===================================
GPU Memory Usage: 520.1  MB
GPU Load :        2.0 %
```

Each command is quite slow, every GPU information that you want to retrieve takes approximately **1.5s**.

Hope this can be helpful for you :)